# Setting the page title in a plugin, but not outside my plugin

Tags: filters

I am writing my first humble plugin, which gets items from a simple database. For good SEO, I want to set the HTML title to be the item name, varying according to my users choice.

My user enters some choices on a form and I show results. Each item has one page and the URL gives me `?item=12345` so I can get the item name from my database. All this works.

I can successfully set the title, by setting up this in my top ("bootstrap"?) file of my plugin:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'dwnz_filter_pagetitle', 20 );
```

to call my function (which queries the database for the item name).

My problem is: this filter is being invoked through the whole website, not just when my plugin is being used. How do I limit this call just to my plugin pages?

Comment: Inside the `dwnz_filter_pagetitle` you need to check what page you're on. If it's not one of yours, just pass the value through the filter unmodified,

Comment: The page title is set by the user, so I can't rely on that as a clue about the plugin. It might be anything.  (My plugin is invoked by a shortcode on any page. Maybe this is the wrong way to start a plugin?)

Answer (score 0):

1) I think I solved it: check if the content contains my shortcode:

a) So set up in my top (outer) plugin file with:

add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'dwnz_filter_pagetitle', 20 );

b) plus later on in same file:

function dwnz_filter_pagetitle ($title) {
    // get_post even works in my case when I am expecting a page, not a post
    $content = get_post();
    if (has_shortcode($content->post_content, 'my_plugin_shortcode')) {

```
   $new_page_title =  get_something_from_my_database();      
   $page_title = $new_page_title;
   return ($page_title);
}
```

}

2) Plus: I solved a similar problem: how do I ensure that my JS was enqueued only for my plugin content, (whereas I had it being enqueued on all output, unneccessary)

a) So set up in my top (outer) plugin file with:

add_shortcode('my_plugin_shortcode', 'my_top_function');

b) In same file:

```
function my_top_function($atts, $content = '', $tag){
   $obj = new my_plugin_class ('my_title', 'my_version');
   $html = $obj->some_method();
   return ($html);

}
```

c) in my_plugin_class, in some_method, first do something that makes my_html and JS markup based on your inputs and logic. (I'm fetching from a database and making some google JS of marker locations). Then I queue  one line for a normal reference to Google, plus another  to append my dynamic JS to the WP queue, so that WP issues it in a standards-compliant way.
The point being, all this only happens if your shortcode has invoked your code at the top.

```
$google_api_key = $this->get_google_api_key();
$google_include = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?'
   . 'v=3.exp&amp;key='.$google_api_key;
$script_id = $this->plugin_name.'_googlemaps';
wp_enqueue_script( $script_id,  
   $google_include, 
   array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, true );
wp_add_inline_script($script_id, 
   $my_dynamic_js_string, 'after' ); 

....
return($my_html);
```

I hope this helps. I'm new to the etiquette here.